# Можно ли считать историю сообщений на IOS

Tags: ios

Хочу написать приложение для себя, для учета расходов, вижу два пути - парсить страничку банка или считывать сис с телефона, которые он отправляет.

Я не писал на iOS ни строчки кода, Но немного погуглив, я понял, что с смс в ios не все так просто, вроде как и можно, но в стор это не пропустят (а оно мне и не надо в принципе). И все же, есть ли возможность считать всю историю сообщений по определенному контакту?

Comment: Скорее всего вам ещё и jailbreak устройства надо будет сделать. Вы действительно готовы на это пойти ради чтения SMS?

Comment: Сам задумался собирать информацию о приходе/уходе денежных средств через сообщения на ios. Интересно, удалось в итоге запустить сбор информации из сообщений? Может, уже какое приложение наэту тему существует?